# Postgres Revoke schema create rights from the user

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to restrict what users can do in the DB. One of the roles has pretty much all rights except 'Superuser' also all objects in DB schemas OWHER is '**ROLE1**'.

I create **user1** and assigned it as a member of the ROLE1
[image]

It's working, but **ROLE1** has allowed the creation of schemas. I want to revoke these rights from **user1** but still have all of the other permissions **ROLE1** is have.

**The question is**: How can I revoke the schema created by the **user1** who is membership of the group **ROLE1**?

```
CREATE USER ser1 WITH PASSWORD 'jw8s0F4';

GRANT ROLE1 TO user1;
```

also, **user1** has this setting

[image]

Comment: remove, extract whatever you want to call it. the user1 should not have right to create new schemas

Answer (score 0):

> I create user1 and assigned it as a member of the ROLE1
>
> It's working, but ROLE1 has allowed the creation of schemas. I want to revoke these rights from user1 but still have all of the other permissions ROLE1 is have.

That cannot work. Create another role that has all the privileges from `role1` except `CREATE` on the database. Then use that role. To avoid duplication, you can revoke all those privileges from `role1` and make it a member of the new role instead.

Comment: this is the issue i cannot add new roles, all objects in DB when by ROLE1

Comment: also correct me if I am wrong but, if ill remove `CREATE ` from the role, they will not be able to create any object, temp table and others something else

Comment: You can never remove a privilege from a role. Privileges are attached to objects. `CREATE` on the database is the right to create a schema in the database. Why can't you add new roles? If you cannot modify the existing situation, you cannot solve the problem.

Comment: how do I apply the same rights as ROLE 1 to the new role? Role 1. has. more than 1K of objects where ROLE1 is the owner. I need to be able to use those objects, but unable to create a schema as ROLE1 does.

Comment: You have to search all the objects owned by ROLE1 (one option would be to run `drop role role1` and look at the messages), then grant privileges on these objects to the new role.